# install4j uninstaller does not delete all files

Tags: install4j

i am generating an installer for a desktop application using install4j 4.0.5 compiled by
j2re1.4.2_08 and running on WindowsXP.The Problem is that The uninstaller does not delete any files unless the files that have been installed by a previous installer.
Example : It install my application into program files folder lets say 
"Vodafone". My application further creates some files and folder into "vodafone"
folder. At the time of uninstall it delete every thing whatever create 
by setup while files and folder created by my application remains 
there in "vodafone" even after restart my machine several time so i need to delete all files inside the installation folder .
I need your support to know how to fix this problem and if there is any workaround i can do to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

The uninstaller does not delete all files and folders in the installation folder. Only the following files will be deleted:

- Files that are contained in the installer and have an uninstallation policy that leads to uninstallation, such as "Always" or "If created".
- Files that were registered with `context.registerUninstallFile(...)` by the installer

If the installation directory is empty after those files have been deleted, the installation directory will be deleted as well.

If you want to delete other externally created files, use the "Delete files or directories" action instead.

Comment: thanks for you reply ,  but i need to know if new files created during the run time in the installation directory so the only way to delete them is to define those files in delete files or directories action

Comment: That is correct, you can also use a "Delete files and directories" action to delete the externally created files.

Comment: the uninstall.exe not workin at all with me in windows 7 and i got the following exception in the error log java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.awt.Dimension.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicProgressBarUI.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.GridBagLayout.getLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.GridBagLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown